# ¿Como pasar un JTable a otro JTable omitiendo las dos ultimas Columnas?

Tags: javascript, java

Intento pasar un JTable1 a JTable2, sin embargo no quiero que se pasen las 2 ultimas columnas del JTable1. De antemano Gracias!!!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Gracias!! gbianchi    Tenia algo de este estilo.                                                 for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount()-5; i++) {
                        Object object = table.getValueAt(j, i);
                        s.addCell(new Label(i, j, String.valueOf(object)));
                    }
                }

Comment: es importante que siempre agregues lo que hiciste a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías ir copiando los valores celda por celda , solo de las columnas que te interesan. Ej: 
JTable1

```
     |col1 |col2 |col3 |col4|
     |1    |2    |3    |4   |
     |5    |6    |7    |8   |
```

El JTable 2 quedaría:

```
                  |col1 |col2 |
                  |1    |2    |
                  |5    |6    |
```

Y el codigo seria:

```
for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
    Object fila[] = new Object[2];
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    fila[0] = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);
    fila[1] = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);
    modelo.addRow(fila);
}
```

No se si eso te sirve para copiarlas, si no entendí bien espero tu respuesta para intentar ayudarte! Saludos!

Comment: Super!!! Nerina me fue de mucha ayuda, Gracias!!! Saludos..